# Julia sets of finite Blaschke products

Tags: complex-dynamics

Is there any book or paper where I can find a detailed discussion of the character of Julia set (Cantor set or the unit circle) depending on zeros and the constant unitary factor of a [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00043v2